# Convert to a non-adjacent form

Tags: code-golf, binary, base-conversion

Consider a form of binary where digits can be any of \$1\$, \$0\$ and \$-1\$. We'll still call this "binary" because we convert the digits from base two. For example,

$$\begin{align}
[1, 0, -1, 1]_2 & = 1 \times 2^3 + 0 \times 2^2 + -1 \times 2^1 + 1 \times 2^0 \\
& = 8 - 2 + 1 \\
& = 7
\end{align}$$

We'll call a representation of a number in this format a "[non-adjacent form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-adjacent_form)" if no non-zero digits are adjacent. \$[1, 0, -1, 1]_2\$ is not a non-adjacent form of \$7\$, as the last two digits are adjacent and non-zero. However, \$[1,0,0,-1]_2\$ is a non-adjacent form of \$7\$.

You should take a positive integer and convert it to a non-adjacent form. As every number has an infinite number of these forms (but only by prepending leading zeroes), you should output the form with no leading zeros. If the standard binary format of the input is a non-adjacent form (e.g. \$5 = 101_2\$), you should output that. You can output a list of integers, or a single string, or any other format the clearly shows the output. You may optionally choose to use any three distinct characters in place of `1`, `0` and `-1`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: May we output in reverse order?

Comment: @Arnauld No, the output should have the least significant bit last

Comment: I literally just read a presentation about non-adjacent binary before seeing this challenge… coincidence?

Comment: @xigoi I guess you could say that your presentation and this challenge were... adjacent :P

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup><s>19</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
-/'2\-2!3 1*
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs9LVVzeK0TVSNFYw1OLiSlMwBWJzIDY0MgKTxgB8vAbB)

Uses Prodinger's algorithm on Wikipedia:

```
Input   x
Output  np, nm
xh = x >> 1;
x3 = x + xh;
c = xh ^ x3;
np = x3 & c;
nm = xh & c;
```

And then the last three steps are not used because the `& c` part of `np` and `nm` erases the 1 bits where both are 1, but we're doing `-/'` so it doesn't matter. (Observation thanks to @m90)

How it translates to K:

```
-2!3 1*    given x, create (3x,x) and floor-divide both by 2
           which gives (x3,xh)
2\         convert to base 2, which gives a two-column matrix
           with lsb being the last row
           1st column is np, 2nd column is nm, but both-1 bits not handled
-/'        evaluate np - nm to get a vector of -1, 0, 1s
```

Comment: The whole `>/1=/'\ ` part can be removed -- the `& c` only changes (1,1) to (0,0), which makes no difference if you're subtracting them.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <sup><s>13</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
;0+HBU_/U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/aQNvDKTReP/T/4fZHTWv@/zfVMdcxNDICYmMA)

-4 bytes (`^/&$` removed) thanks to @m90's observation that we don't need to clear shared 1 bits.

Look ma, no Unicode!

Literal translation of Prodinger's algorithm. x3 goes before xh, and `U` is used twice to align the binary representations of the two.

Comment: Well, *technically*, these are still in Unicode, they just happen to also be in ASCII :P

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?f(n+n%4/3>>1)+'OPON'[n%4]:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PPk0jTztP1UTf2M7OUFNb3T/A3089GigQa6Wu/j8tv0hBI1PBVsHQWiFTwUbByABIa2trKiTn5xXn56Tq5eSna2TqKKRpZGpqWv8HAA)

Output `O` for `0`, `P` for `1`, `N` for `-1`.

-2 bytes by Arnauld.

---

Alternatively, as suggested by Arnauld, using `1` for `1`, <s>`2` for `0`,</s> `0` for `0`, and, `3` for `-1`:

## JavaScript, 31 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?f(n+n%4/3>>1)+n%2*n%4:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdNDkAwEEDhq8xGtOqflWqdRUplRGakxPWrq/e9c/3WxwW834p422P0hoylxQtSlI3NYG0nk/oi3ZTn0XMAgWCg04AwQ9@mKiXBMT187fXFh8ASvEApdfwB)

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes with `n+n%4/3>>1`.

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcZLDkAwEADQq8xGtKk/K7QOIhYNKiMyI4hV715W7@32tfd84fmkxMsagtOkDQ1OkKKoyWtjSqnGv95XUxvHwfEFAkFD2QFCD1Xxq5SEmenmY80O3gQm4ARK2YUP) by using `1`, `2`, `3`.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Python 3, <s>176</s> 103 bytes

Literal translation of Prodinger's algorithm. By no means the shortest python 3 answer that should be attainable. it's been a while on here so looking forward to getting back into it!

```
x=int(input())
h=x>>1
t=h+x
c=h^t
p=bin(t&c)
m=bin(h&c)
n=[]
j=len(p)-2
k=len(m)-2
for i in range(j):n.append(int(p[i+2]))
for i in range(k):n[j-k+i]=-int(m[i+2])*(m[i+2]==0)or 1
print(n)
```

If anyone can help shorten it I'd appreciate it, there must be an easier way to concatenate the two positive and negative value lists.

Using [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752/m90)'s answer it can be shortened vastly predominately by using zip!

```
enter code x=int(input())
print([*[int(x)-int(y)for x,y in zip(*[f".{x//2+z:0{len(bin(x*3))-3}b}"for z in[x,0]])]])
```

Comment: I'm not too good at Python either, but here it's already a bit shorter: [142 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEIXh/ZyiK8nQdtG4K0wvEiLYUs1QMw0hQgTvHp3l4/t56VPCKdfWKrEUw5LexSBCoLosExQKfYWNwq1AHIRWFhMuGw5O6xUfZ@7WjqVTKH9wdvYeDnrtYiKOFrRgLfJdnrs5cBanKDgePfsvjfoUHffWI6SsS7C1ydof).

Comment: [Some different improvements make it 103](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoQwDADvvqJ4SmpFt70JvqR4EVY2sMQiFdKKb68WBoaBCSn@dnalyEwcgTicERCbcNT02lcJ9lUJt/1QYpIiVpkCaL@1lwyD7fI0Xv8vw0oMoh1i7@71buuf39uLGZcFX0r5WPsA "Python 3 – Try It Online") -- including using the observation that the `& c` only changes (1,1) to (0,0), which makes no difference if one is subtracting them.

Comment: @m90 I knew there had to be a better way to combine them all together, that's a great answer, I think my biggest failure was not really understanding the maths behind it.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>21</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0‚¬2÷+2вí`(0ζRO
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@m90*, thanks to his observation that `& c` only changes `[1,1]` to `[0,0]`, which doesn't matter when we're subtracting them.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//zDigJrCrDLDtysy0LLDrWAoMM62Uk///zEyMg) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/g0cNsw6tMTq8XdvowqbDaxM0DM5tC/L/r/M/2lTHXMfQyAiIjWMB).

**Explanation:**

```python
0‚        # Pair the (implicit) input with 0
  ¬       # Get the first item of this pair (the input) without popping
   2÷     # Integer-divide it by 2
     +    # Add it to both the input and 0 in the pair
          # (we now have the pair [input+input//2, input//2])
      2в  # Convert both inner values to a binary-list
í         # Reverse each inner list
 `        # Pop and push both lists separated to the stack
  (       # Negate all values in the top list
   0ζ     # Zip the two lists together with 0 as filler
     R    # Reverse the list of pairs back again
      O   # Sum each inner pair together
          # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I wonder if a port of [my naive attempt](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w6KSghzunP9q47lHjjoe7@kI8HzXMfLhrwbFNiQ93tDxq3HNo6cnpx9pBkjsW/dc53H500sOdM1S8NSOBeg0A) would be shorter. Essentially it gets the Cartesian power of `[1,0,-1]` for each \$1 \le i \le n\$ (\$n\$ being the input), then gets the first one that is both a non-adjacent form, and that, when converted from base 2, equals \$n\$

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing It appears to be [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//1sxwq7FuE7Do8qSMs6yUX3KksOEw7wqT199WsOEI///MTIy) as well, haha. :D Will add it to my answer as well. Maybe someone sees something to golf in either or multiple of the approaches.

Comment: The second one can be shortened to [`0‚¬2÷+2вí\`0ζRε\`-`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/g0cNsw6tMTq8XdvowqbDaxMMzm0LOrc1Qfd/rc7/aFMdcx1DIyMgNo4FAA), using the observation that the `& c` only changes (1,1) to (0,0), which makes no difference if one is subtracting them.

Comment: @m90 Nice observation! Actually saves 2 more bytes, because the ``ε`+`` can simply be a sum of inner lists with `O`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n>0?f[(n-w=n%2*(2-n%4))/2]+[w]:[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/OwD4tWiNPt9w2T9VIS8NIN0/VRFNT3yhWO7o81io6tvZ/gYKGoZ6eoYGBpl5uYoGGWprmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>103</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>96</s></sup> 94 bytes

```c
m;i;f(n){int r[n];for(i=!n,n+=*r=m=n/2;n;n/=2,m/=2)r[i++]=n%2-m%2;for(;i--;)putchar(r[i]+49);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVVhj6IwEP2@v6JnYgIC0Smgki735XK/Qs3GIO6R065h3Zw5418/ryDSKTMkknHmzbzOPNoWUXHY6vf7/agqtfe0f630WdQrvVH7j9qr8m861EE@qfNjrqdSaaWnuQyP5uXXqyoINrkey@g4li1eVVGk/NPXufi1rT0D2ARJ5qvbval63Fba88X1RZincZSXU1mcy91stRG5uMJNOW54uOXALTt3OMTHfSCcDUKJDQ2zUhsaMs1RQZK3QCUJ3xIHh5kZDg45YYbWQ1IBnCURXpBunOTHbpywJ05XND91GqP8czdO8hdunPA7g2P6z5zpNPzka3o7PDCf1d/yY@/1H5k/7TwT6wrFAAUUBRQlKUpSVExRMUUlFJVQVEpRKUXNKWpOUQuKWlDUkqKWFJVRVMZMlRk@cNPnxs/MHxgBgFEAGAmA0QAYEYBRARgZgNEBGCGAUQIYKYDRAhgxgFEDGDmMz26SSb9LHnuk3wmh3WLWlNaMrZlYM7Xm3JoLay6tmSEKTIf4ABECYgRECYgTECkgVkC0kHXdNzfSxLzL4ndZP7ofrS8/5fqS/TC/dBQK/D8edXnmWhNec75UeldeTNpMdebrcPx0@L4SQdCin/fe87TSplIbUL37VJvA3huNlzsRfRdmQdq30eZyVriE0dLU6PVsi20chDgggDkWh5An4Vo/QR1viXn7/rveTd@Hti3ckrP@XVPC3P2oyo0hjeiz1qMu6fZyu/8r9oft@@c9@vMf)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs positive integer \$n\$.
Outputs \$n\$ converted to its non-adjacent form using \$2\$ for \$1\$s, \$1\$ for \$0\$s, and \$0\$ for \$-1\$s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,s="":x and f(round(x/2))+".+.-"[x%4]or""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoMwDADQq4TAIKHqoO6r4EnGPiq1M7ClEhXq6et723WsRcfW8vSL/zlFqN0@IYYKURNksnJqovr0zA4HN/T4ro/Xpxhiy8VAQBQs6nch7zlsJnqQdJmEud0) Outputs using `.` for `0`, `+` for `1` and `-` for `-1`. Explanation: Port of @tsh's JavaScript solution, except that Python has Banker's rounding which saves a byte in Python 3. Or I could have just use Python 2 I guess.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
ＮθＷθ«←§.+.-θ≔÷⁺¬﹪⊕θ⁴θ²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoIwFETXcIqG1W8sJBhXsiJxQ6KEKyD9SpPSSvuLJsaz1@pqJnnzZppHN9lRx9iZR6A@LFd0sPImf85KI0uVvfNscMoQHM94I8Fa6ozEFxTVrioLwVae5lnrvbob6Ayd1KYkwqCDh94SXKwM2iYyOVzQEMr0KtiB/1TB9v9s8k@MdR3LTX8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs using `.` for `0`, `+` for `1` and `-` for `-1`. Explanation: Another port of @tsh's JavaScript solution.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number to convert.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until it is zero.

```
←§.+.-θ
```

Output the previous digit using cyclic indexing. The digits are output right-to-left so that the final output is in the correct order.

```
≔÷⁺¬﹪⊕θ⁴θ²θ
```

Divide by two, rounding to even.

Comment: I quite like the `←` RTL output trick! Nice usage of a language specific feature :)